# Angular2 accessing parent component in a dynamic modal

Tags: angular, angular2-services

So I have created a dynamic modal service, that is meant to render given component in the current view.

**Modal Service:**

```
import {
  Injectable,
  Component,
  ComponentResolver,
  ComponentMetadata,
  ReflectiveInjector
} from '@angular/core';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal-cmp';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  viewContainerRef: any;
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) { }


  create(cmp) {
    if(this.viewContainerRef) {
      this.resolveComponent(cmp).then( factory => {
        this.createShell(factory.selector, cmp).then( generated => {
          this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(generated);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  private resolveComponent(cmp) {
    return this.resolver.resolveComponent(cmp);
  }

  private createShell(selector, cmp) {
    const metadata = new ComponentMetadata({
      selector: 'dynamic-tpl',
      template: `
        <app-modal>
           <${selector}></${selector}>
        </app-modal>
      `,
      directives: [ ModalComponent, cmp ]
    });
    const cmpClass = class DynamicTpl {};
    const decorated = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
    return this.resolveComponent(decorated);
  }

  setViewContainerRef(vcr:any) {
    this.viewContainerRef = vcr;
  }

}
```

**Modal Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: 'modal.component.html'
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('modalRef') modalRef;
  element: HTMLElement;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.element = this.modalRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.element.classList.add('entering');
    })
  }

  public destroy() {
    this.element.classList.remove('entering');
    this.element.classList.add('leaving');
    const transitionEnd = () => {
      console.log('modal closed');
      this.element.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnd);
      this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);
    }

    this.element.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnd);
  }



}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DuPU6uBgu0lcHtVrr5ir?p=preview

So the idea was to have a modal component, that handles transitions and positioning, while the service handles dynamic creating. But there is a problem with this model, or at least the execution. I cannot access ModalComponent methods from its children components, hence I can't close the modal from within a child(for example on saving the modal data). The questions are the following:

How can be the model improved ? 
How can I access Modals Component from a child component ?